# Grails application not running after macOS upgrade

Tags: java, macos, gradle, grails, macos-big-sur

After upgrading my macOS to Big Sur, I have not been able to run my grails application. I keep getting this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':server:compileGroovy'.

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

I have reinstalled java, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to see java paths: /usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk

Copying tools.jar in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ solved the problem.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the `JavaAppletPlugin` to build a Grails app.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home` as your `JAVA_HOME`?